# debug with no errors or warnings

Tags: c, gcc

The following code compiles with no error or warnings, I can also execute the program and it will act as expected in that it will return the error messages at locations it is expected, for example, providing arguments to non-existent files. This lets me know the code is working as far as line 28 (close of the !fpc section)

Meaning there must be an issue from the

```
register int ch, i;
```

Down to

```
return (1);
```

before

```
printf("\"%s\"\n",line);\
```

The program is expected to take command line arguments of the program name itself and two file names, it then opens both of these files, and should then copy strings from the first file up to a max length to the second file while adding `"` to both the start and end of the string in the new file.

The code I have is

**fgetline.c**

```
#include "fgetline.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: enquote filetocopy filetowrite \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Couldn't open copy file: (%d) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    fpc = fopen(argv[2], "r+");
    if (!fpc) {
        printf("Couldn't open write file: (%d) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    register int ch, i;

    ch = getc(fp);
    if (ch == EOF)
        return -1;

    i = 0;
    while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && i < max) {
        line[i++] = ch;
        ch = getc(fp);
    }
    line[i] = '\0';

    while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        ch = getc(fp);
        i++;
    }
    return(i);

    printf("\"%s\"\n",line);

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpc);
    return 0;
}
```

**fgetline.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int fgetline(FILE *fp, char *line, int max);
FILE *fp, *fpc;
#define max 30
char line[max + 1];
```

I am compiling with

```
debian:~/uni/Ass0$ gcc fgetline.c -Wall -o enquote
debian:~/uni/Ass0$ cd /
```

testing I did was

```
debian:~/uni/Ass0$ ./enquote
usage: enquote filetocopy filetowrite
debian:~/uni/Ass0$ ./enquote test
usage: enquote filetocopy filetowrite
debian:~/uni/Ass0$ ./enquote test frog
Couldn't open write file: (2) No such file or directory
debian:~/uni/Ass0$ ./enquote monkey frog
Couldn't open copy file: (2) No such file or directory
debian:~/uni/Ass0$ cat test
ting
test
123

tim@debian:~/uni/Ass0$ cat test2
tim@debian:~/uni/Ass0$ ./enquote test test2
tim@debian:~/uni/Ass0$ cat test2
```

expected result would be when I run ./enquote test test2, would copy

```
ting
test
123
```

from `test` to `test2` so it would appear like

```
"ting"
"test"
"123"
```

Thanks, not sure how much more info to give.

Comment: 1) Enable **all** warnings! `-Wall` is far away from "all" 2) No errors/warnings does not guarantee correct code. 3) Reformat your code. GNU-style is soo very 80ies.

Comment: @Olaf, what are t/he flags for all the warnings, quick search turned up -Wextra what else, ok tried with Wextra, still no luck.

Comment: @Ausghostdog My current set is `gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wdisabled-optimization -Wendif-labels -Winline -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wformat=2 -Wnull-dereference -Winit-self -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -O2`.

Comment: Don't define variables in header files.

Comment: Don't use `register`.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to ask your question. What do you want to know?

Comment: `fpc` is currently unused.

Comment: You have a random `return i;` statement in the middle of `main`.

Comment: Don't use lowercase letters for your macro names, especially not `max`.

Comment: You've declared a function called `fgetline` but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: @melpomene, thanks can I ask switches you used to find those errors or just going off experience ?

Comment: What about point 2 in my comment was unclear? Don't stop reading comments after the first sentence.

Comment: @Ausghostdog My comments are just from looking at the code.

Comment: @melpomene, thanks for the gcc invoke commands, using all of them gave the warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]
  register int ch, i;
which I have now fixed by removing the register, I'll work on getting fpc actually getting the stream from fp and will move the variables out of the header.

Comment: @olaf, I understand that no errors or codes mean my code is not perfect, if something doesn't give me an idea my code is correct or at least a place to start then I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @Ausghostdog Ah, you have an older gcc defaulting to gnu89 mode. You can avoid that warning by adding `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: No, that's not what I wrote. Fundamental logic. **You** have to ensure your code is correct, which means you have to test (read about unit tests)

Comment: @melpomene version is gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
 will see what I can get off the DEbian repos in a way of an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues with your code, compiling with all warnings enabled would have spotted some of them:

- Declaring global variables in a header file is good practice, but not defining them there.  The `extern` keyword is used for declarations.  The definitions belong in the C file.  In this case, variables such as `fp`, `fp1`, `line` should be defined as local variables, not global variables.
- Output file `argv[2]` should be open with `"w"` mode, `"r+"` is used for updated mode and will fail if the file does not exist.  Update mode is very tricky and confusing, avoid using it.
- Do not use the `register` keyword, it is obsolete now as compilers are smart enough to determine how to best use registers.
- Your `while` loops will read just 2 lines from the input file, storing the first into the `line` array and discarding the second one.
- The `return (i);` statement exits the program, no output is performed, the remaining statements in the function are ignored completely (-Wall might have spotted this error).

You can simplify the problem by considering this: You want to output a `"` at the beginning of each line and before the `'\n'` at the end of each line.  You do not need to buffer the line in memory, which would impose a limit on line length.  Just output the `"` whenever you start a line and before you end one:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp, *fpc;
    int ch, last;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: enquote filetocopy filetowrite\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file: (%d) %s\n",
               errno, strerror(errno));
        return 2;
    }

    fpc = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (!fpc) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file: (%d) %s\n",
               errno, strerror(errno));
        return 2;
    }

    last = '\n';  // we are at the beginning of a line
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (last == '\n') {
            fputc('"', fpc);  // " at the beginning of a line
        }
        if (ch == '\n') {
            fputc('"', fpc);  // " at the end of a line
        }
        fputc(ch, fpc);
        last = ch;
    }
    if (last != '\n') {
        // special case: file does not end with a \n
        fputc('"', fpc);  // " at the end of a line
        fputc('\n', fpc);  // put a \n at the end of the output file
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and also for the explanation. Seems like I have a very long way to go on C.

Comment: @Ausghostdog: It does take a lot of work to become proficient in C, but the skills you will acquire will be useful for a variety of other more forgiving languages. Keep studying, it is worth it!